# Azure DevOps see included commits in build

Tags: github, azure-devops

we are using Azure Pipelines to build and deploy various projects. We are using Enterprise Github service connection as our git repository source which we are using as part of the build pipelines that are running on on-prem AzureDevops build agent. We are then using on-prem hosted DevOps agents to deploy the service on our on-prem servers.

If we trigger a build we then receive an email notification about all the new commits which are included in the build. Is the same information (what commits are part of the build) included somewhere in the Azure DevOps UI? I was not able to find it and it's really difficult to then determine what I'm actually deploying our various environments as I'm not always the one who triggers each build.

Thanks

Comment: There should be a button called "View changes" on the page that shows the information about a pipeline run. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62571796/azure-devops-pipeline-view-changes-show-wrong-number-of-changes.

Comment: Such button does not exist on our projects when we open particular build run. See screenshot.

https://imgur.com/S1pC0Sc